# Why do subfields conflict when they are in different interfaces?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am trying to query a single MongoDB document (`trivia`) using GraphQL (Apollo Server), but am having trouble with one of the document fields.

`LightningRoundQuestion.answer` and `PictureRoundPicture.answer` should return a `String`, and `MultipleChoiceRoundQuestion.answer` should return an `Int`. See the schema:

`schema`

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  # ROOT TYPES ==================================================
  type Query {
    trivia(_id: String!): Trivia
  }

  # INTERFACES ==================================================
  interface Round {
    type: String!
    theme: String!
    pointValue: Int!
  }

  type LightningRound implements Round {
    type: String!
    theme: String!
    pointValue: Int!
    questions: [LightningRoundQuestion]
  }

  type MultipleChoiceRound implements Round {
    type: String!
    theme: String!
    pointValue: Int!
    questions: [MultipleChoiceRoundQuestion]
  }

  type PictureRound implements Round {
    type: String!
    theme: String!
    pointValue: Int!
    pictures: [PictureRoundPicture]
  }

  # QUERY TYPES =================================================
  type LightningRoundQuestion {
    question: String!
    answer: String!
  }

  type MultipleChoiceRoundQuestion {
    question: String!
    options: [String!]!
    answer: Int!
  }

  type PictureRoundPicture {
    url: String!
    answer: String!
  }

  type Trivia {
    _id: String!
    createdAt: String!
    triviaId: String!
    triviaPin: String!
    host: String!
    rounds: [Round]!
    tieBreaker: TieBreaker!
  }

  type TieBreaker {
    question: String
    answer: Int
  }
`
```

`resolvers & server`

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    trivia: async (root, { _id }) => {
      return triviaCollection.findOne(ObjectId(_id))
    }
  },
  Round: {
    __resolveType(obj) {
      if (obj.type === 'multipleChoice') {
        return 'MultipleChoiceRound'
      } else if (obj.type === 'lightning') {
        return 'LightningRound'
      } else if (obj.type === 'picture') {
        return 'PictureRound'
      }
    }
  }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`Server ready at ${url}`)
})
```

`query`

```
query {
  trivia(_id: "5e827a4e1c9d4400009fea32") {
    _id
    createdAt
    triviaId
    triviaPin
    host
    rounds {
      ... on LightningRound {
        questions {
          question
          answer
        }
      }
      ... on MultipleChoiceRound {
        questions {
          question
          options
          answer
        }
      }
      ... on PictureRound {
        pictures {
          url
          answer
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error message:

```
"message": "Fields \"questions\" conflict because subfields \"answer\" conflict because they return conflicting types \"String!\" and \"Int!\". Use different aliases on the fields to fetch both if this was intentional."
```

Not quite sure what to do next, I looked at [Alias in the Apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/resources/graphql-glossary/#alias), but there's little help there.

Comment: try prefix/rename conflicting field, f.e. `intAnswer:answer` in multiple ?

Comment: That worked! While it makes sense, it's a little annoying that I have to use a workaround just because the "answer" field in the db is consistent across all documents, it cannot be consistent across GraphQL...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a gotcha when using abstract types and occurs as a result of how GraphQL handles merging field selections. What it boils down to is that if you request a field with the same name (or alias) multiple times inside the same selection set, the field has to return the same type. In the above schema, it doesn't -- questions could have the type `[LightningRoundQuestion]`, or `[PictureRoundPicture]` and so on.

For a detailed explanation, see [this section](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Field-Selection-Merging) of the spec.

There's two workarounds for this. On the client side, you can use aliases to ensure GraphQL won't try to merge the fields in the first place:

```
rounds {
  ... on LightningRound {
    lightningQuestions: questions {
      question
      answer
    }
  }
  ... on MultipleChoiceRound {
    multipleChoiceQuestions: questions {
      question
      options
      answer
    }
  }
}
```

This is your best bet when you can't change the schema. However, you can also just change the names of the fields on the server-side for better client-side DX.

```
rounds {
  ... on LightningRound {
    lightningQuestions {
      question
      answer
    }
  }
  ... on MultipleChoiceRound {
    multipleChoiceQuestions {
      question
      options
      answer
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that we don't have to do that with, `type`, `theme` or `pointValue` because these fields have the same type across all your implementing types.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Totally makes sense. Option 1 works great. Option 2 doesn't work because the field in the database is labeled "questions" and not "multipleChoiceQuestions", so it cannot find that field.

Comment: @SamSverko your GraphQL schema does not have to match your database schema. You can, for example, provide a resolver for `multipleChoiceQuestions` like `(round) => round.questions`.

Comment: Where would I implement that? Do you have a discord for a quick chat about this, I've no idea where to implement this in the schema/resolver :/ SamTheBigs#3861

Comment: `const resolvers = { MultipleChoiceRound: { multipleChoiceQuestions: () => {...} } }`

Comment: What do I put inside that? What do I change in the schema? I keep seeing: `[Error: MultipleChoiceRound.multipleChoiceQuestions defined in resolvers, but not in schema]`